# Compare two files, print the first word which are unchanged in second file

Tags: shell

I have **fileA** with following content:

```
12345:$gfdgfgfgfgfgfgfdgdgfgfdgfdg/:17436:0:99999:7:::
67890:$kjhwhkjhwekjrhwkejhwkjehkjl/:17433:0:99999:7:::
14567:$aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa/:17437:0:99999:7:::
```

I have **fileB** with the following content

```
12345:$gfdgfgfgfgfgfgfdgdgfgfdgfdg/:17436:0:99999:7:::
14567:$bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb/:17437:0:99999:7:::
67890:$ccccccccccccccccccccccccccc/:17433:0:99999:7:::
```

I want to compare **fileA** and **fileB**. If any lines in fileB are unchanged compared to fileA, then I want to print the first word of that line.

So, the output should be just the following as per the example I have given above.

```
12345
```

I tried my luck with `diff` and `comm`. But, the lines in **fileB** may not appear in the same order as they appear in **fileA**.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This awk one-liner should do the job:

```
awk -F':' 'NR==FNR{a[$0]=1;next}a[$0]{print $1}' fileA fileB
```

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -f fileA fileB | awk -F: '{print $1}'
```

Comment: How does this handle the order of files?

Comment: what if the content in fileA has `.*`?

Comment: Since OP did not show that kind of data, I omit those case. But you're right, the method cannot adopt special characters for regex in FileA.